# "con vista a la playa" vs "con vistas a la playa"

Tags: diferencias-regionales

I have always heard "con vista a algo", but today I have read "con vistas a la playa" in an apartment ad :

> Apartamento con vistas a la playa
>
> San Vicente de la Barquera, Cantabria, Espanha
>
> Precioso apartamento situado a tan solo 50 metros de la playa. Tiene plaza de garaje y tiene todos los servicios de restaurantes y supermercado en la misma calle. Ideal para vacaciones en familia. Muy luminoso, todo exterior y con vistas a la playa.

I assume both expressions are correct? Which one is the most usual? Does it depend on the country?

Comment: That's interesting. I've always heard "con vistas a la playa" in Spain, while the other option sounds a bit strange. Maybe it's a case of regional differences.

Comment: In Argentina, we'd only say "con vista a la playa." "con vistas a la playa" would suggest to me that the place offers different views of the seaside.

Comment: @Gustavson that's exactly what I thought when I read it, probably because the expression in Portuguese (my native language) is also in singular.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' as I have read it on an AirBNB ad and it will probably be deleted after a while, I'll quote the text in the question instead of linking to the ad.

Comment: It must be regional. For whatever it's worth, I don't find it strange to say "con vista a la playa" but rather than say "playa" I typically say "mar" instead. (So, "con vista al mar.") I do think some things like word choice and plurality are affected by regional speech.

Answer (score 4):

In Spain, as pointed by Charlie, it's mainly used in its plural form:

> con **vistas** a la playa.

In the DRAE you can find that they are both **equivalents**:

> [**vista**](https://dle.rae.es/vista)
> 5. f. Panorama que se ofrece al espectador desde un punto.
>  **U. t. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing**. *Una ventana con muy buenas vistas.*

The highlighted text may be translated as:

> Used too in plural form with the same meaning as singular

Answer (score 1):

In Argentina, *"con vista a la playa"* is exclusively used. *"Con vistas a la playa"* would mean that the location you are referring to has more than one view to the beach, which is not very common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case it interests somebody, that is closer to Portuguese, in which we always say "com vista para a praia" (in singular).